# $b^{a^{1/n}}$: is it an irrational number?

Tags: number-theory

A power type $b^{a^{1/n}}$ where $b$, $a$ and $n$ are positive integers greater than $1$ and $a^{1/n}$ is irrational, always represents an irrational number?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is in fact transcendental by the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem).